# jQuery datepicker gets the class 'hasDatepicker' but doesn't show the datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker

Im trying to add a datepicker to a form on a wordpress website.
Datepicker doesn't show up but it does give the class 'hasDatepicker' to my element. Any idea on why it would not show the datepicker ?

Edit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('[id*="datepicker"]').each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

scripts are enqueued in the theme

Comment: Post some code please.. A demo preferable in **jsfiddle**

Comment: Post your Code Please

Comment: http://bit.ly/1gCR2oD
Have a look on the website : will add code shortley if needed

Answer (score 4):

@Dylan your problem very simple. It works but can't be show because of z-index.

```
#ui-datepicker-div {z-index:9999 !important}
```

this css will solve your problem

Comment: Still the right answer after so many years :-)